# могу ли я заряжать 3 последовательно соединенные через плату контроля заряда и разряда аккумулятора 18650 от одного источника питания?

Tags: arduino, электроника

Есть проект на ардуино. Для его питания потребовалось параллельно соединить 3 последовательно соединенных через bms аккумулятора 18650. Могу ли я заряжать их от общего источника питания(к примеру, если я подведу на клемы необходимый ток и от этих клем буду заряжать каждую последовательную сборку)? Если нет, то подскажите как их лучше заряжать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните, так они последовательно или параллельно соединены?

Comment: @Kromster, 4 банки соединены последовательно, и 3 таких последовательно соединенных сборок соединены параллельно

Comment: @Kromster, нарисовал примерную схему

Comment: При проблемах одной сборки встанет колом зарядка всех трёх. Так что хотя бы диодами их развязать, что ли...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам стоит соединить их по схеме 4S3P (4-в-серию, 3-параллельно) с использованием зярядника с балансировщиком:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. также вопрос на Electrical Engineering: [Diy 18650 4s battery pack [How to charge, how to build?]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/317019)